# Unix Shell script to open an URL in google chrome without xtg-open command

Tags: shell, unix, curl

Can anyone please help me on writing a simple shell script to open an URL (which will ask for userid and pwd) by providing userid and pwd in the script itself.
I have tried "xdg-open https://www.google.com" but i got ***xdg-open: command not found***. Can anyone suggest is any other command is there to fetch an URL?

```
    #!/bin/bash
    xdg-open https://www.google.com 
AND
    #!/bin/bash
    curl -u -username -pwd https://www.google.com
```

I tried both the commands but no luck. Appreciate your help. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could simply do:

```
google-chrome www.google.com
```

And to get help for command use:

```
google-chrome --help
```

Comment: Hello, It seems google-chrome command is not found :( .

    -bash-4.1$ google-chrome --help
    -bash: google-chrome: command not found